# Enumerating Tri-vertex transitive polyhedra n > 3 faces

Tags: polyhedra, enumerative-combinatorics

How many unique vertex transitive polyhedra exist where each vertex has 3 incident edges
for polyhedra with n (= # faces) > 3 ?

Answer (score 3):

The complete list of vertex transitive planar graphs was determined in 1979 by Fleischner and Imrich.  See [here](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/131785/MathSlov_29-1979-2_1.pdf). To quote:

Theorem 3. The connected, simple, planar vertex-transitive graphs are the single
vertex, the single edge, simple circuits and the nets of the uniform convex
polyhedra, namely the nets of regular prisms and antiprisms, the Platonic and the
Archimedian bodies.

Answer (score 0):

See

MR0130841 (24 #A695) Reviewed 
Tutte, W. T.
A census of planar triangulations. 
Canad. J. Math. 14 1962 21–38. 
05.65 (52.45)

Comment: You missed "vertex transitive" in the question, I believe.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Yes, I did :(